# Build fails when image_picker is added to the app that is using firebase_auth in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication, imagepicker

The build is successful and works fine when I am using firebase_auth, When i Started including the image_picker library in flutter, suddenly the build crashes. These are the errors that i got when i tried running:

```
 J:\flutter_projects\webdoc>flutter run --enable-software-rendering
Using software rendering with device AOSP on IA Emulator. You may get better performance with hardware mode by
configuring hardware rendering for your device.
Launching lib\main.dart on AOSP on IA Emulator in debug mode...
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:preDebugBuild'.
> Android dependency 'androidx.core:core' has different version for the compile (1.0.0) and runtime (1.0.2) classpath. You should manually set the same version via DependencyResolution

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 25s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                        26.0s
The built failed likely due to AndroidX incompatibilities in a plugin. The tool is about to try using Jetfier to solve
the incompatibility.
Building plugin firebase_auth...
Running Gradle task 'assembleAarRelease'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleAarRelease'... Done                    2.2s


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'firebase_auth'.
> SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s


The plugin firebase_auth could not be built due to the issue above.
```

**versions of the project are**

```
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  firebase_auth: ^0.15.3
  flushbar: ^1.9.1
  image_picker: ^0.6.2+3
  http: ^0.12.0+2
```

**I even tried using image_picker 0.4.12+1 that doesnt work either** 
I tried setting jetifier= false, but that doesnt fix the issue.

Build.gradle is

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Update the `android-gradle` to the following:

```
dependencies {
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'
}
```

and use the most recent version of `image_picker` i.e 0.6.2+3.

If you also get the following error:

> SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable

Then you need to execute the following in the terminal:

```
export ANDROID_HOME="YOUR_SDK_PATH"
```

Answer (score 0):

Updating the build.gradle to version 3.3.1 and using the most recent version of firebase_auth and image_picker, also change the  distribution url to

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip
```

**libraries:**

```
  firebase_auth: ^0.15.3
  image_picker: ^0.6.2+3
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing my project from D:/ file to C:/ file works for me because my flutter is downloaded in C:/ file.